# Rotate hue on hover and remove grayscale filter

Tags: html, css, filter, css-animations

I have a colored image. I have a grayscale filter applied on initial load. And on hover I remove the grayscale filter. However id also like to rotate the color   of the hue filter on hover. But I am a bit confused why its not working.

Thanks for any help!

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/capf3mq9/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="duplicater0" class="flavNameDescBox addnewflavorimg col-4"> 
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .addnewflavorimg img{
    margin-left:-21px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

  .addnewflavorimg img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    -webkit-animation: hue 3s infinite;
    animation: hue 3s infinite;
    }
```

Comment: You want it to rotate 360deg?

Comment: @EpaXapate I want it to make a full rotation and continue to rotate until hover off

Comment: on second thought a full rotation once around would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? By using `@keyframes`, you can `hue-rotate` from `0deg` to `360deg`

https://jsfiddle.net/1Ljys5gj/

```
@keyframes hue {
  0% {
   -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
   -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.addnewflavorimg img{
    margin-left:-21px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

  .addnewflavorimg img:hover{
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    -webkit-animation: hue 3s infinite;
    animation: hue 3s infinite;
    }

   @keyframes hue{
       0%{
           transform: rotate(0deg);
       }
       100%{
           transform: rotate(360deg);
       }
   }
```

```html
<div id="duplicater0" class="flavNameDescBox addnewflavorimg col-4"> 
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That spins the image around. But how do we rotate the hue's color?

Comment: What do you mean the hue's color?

Comment: I just want it to rotate through the entire color spectrum. I can rotate the hue no problem. I just cant animate it. Like 360 degrees

Comment: Probably because it can't be applied that filter to that particular image.

Comment: but they do it with this image in the codepen i linked above

http://dulmage.me/sites/codepen/logo_bloomberg.png